# How do I remove the slash at the end of a url?

Tags: html, .htaccess, url

Currently, the only way to get to a link on my website it to have a slash at the end of the url like www.me.com/portfolio/ How can I remove the slash at the very end?

Comment: Are you asking how to do it sitewide?

Comment: It's actually just in one sub directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Remove slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I believe this would work. Put it in the directory you want to do this in.

Comment: Thanks. This is probably a stupid question,but just so I don't assume, I do replace the "domain.com" portion with my actual domain name right?  Thanks again!

Comment: Yes. I always forget to do that myself and spend 15 minutes wondering why I'm constantly redirected to domain.com XD